# UIScrollView With Freeform UIViewController and AutoLayout

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout, uistoryboard

So i have a freeform View Controller in iOS To Which i have assigned UIScrollView.. In The Storyboard.

[image: This is the how i have done it]

The constraints i am using.

[image]

So this is how i have done it as you can see. if in the preview i put iPhone 4 inch the takes up the whole space.

Can i have a way so that i can put 2 imageViews on the ScrollView like this and if i run it on any device 1 image View will take up the whole screen so

i will basically end up with 2 pages in the scrollView as i will enable paging

Comment: What all constraints you are applying on ImageView and ScrollView?

Comment: I have edited the question to show constraints. @Gandalf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you have given `fixed width constraint` to both the image view's, so it won't be correct on different screen size. You need to have the width of image view same as that of scroll view.
`imageview1.width = scrollView.width`

`Control Click` on `Image1` and Drag the cursor to Scroll View. There you will see an `equal width constraint` option, select it. For Image2 do the same. Delete those fixed width constraints you have applied. This should work for you.
Also there is no need for `image2.Top == image1.Top`. You should be aligning the top and bottom of both imageview's to superview's top and bottom.

Comment: Thanks Very much !